# Null check operator used on a null value when using CircleAvatar in flutter

Tags: flutter

Today I want to add a avatar to the rss channel, this is the code(flutter 2.x):

```
return Card(
      key: Key(counter.value.id.toString()),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 20,
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      'https://source.unsplash.com/50x50/?portrait',
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                      child:Text(
                      counter.value.subName,
                      softWrap: true,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      )),
                    ),
                  if(isFav.value == 1)
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8,bottom: 8.0,right: 1),
                      child: ButtonTheme(
                          minWidth: 50,
                          height: 30.0,
                          child: RaisedButton.icon(
                            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            icon: Icon(
                              Feather.check_circle,
                              size: 16,
                            ),
                            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                            onPressed: () => touchSub(counter.value.id.toString(),SubStatus.UNSUB),
                            label: Text("已订阅"),
                          )
                      ),
                    )
                  ,
                  if(isFav.value != 1)
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8,bottom: 8.0,right: 1),
                      child: ButtonTheme(
                          minWidth: 50,
                          height: 30.0,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                            onPressed: () => touchSub(counter.value.id.toString(),SubStatus.SUB),
                            child: Text("订阅"),
                          )
                      ),
                    )
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    child:Text(
                        counter.value.intro,
                        softWrap: true,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                        )),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

when I added this code snip:

```
CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 20,
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      'https://source.unsplash.com/50x50/?portrait',
                    ),
                  ),
```

shows error:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
Null check operator used on a null value
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  CircleAvatar file:///home/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/lib/src/component/channel_item_card.dart:67:19
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
Null check operator used on a null value
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  CircleAvatar file:///home/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/lib/src/component/channel_item_card.dart:67:19
====================================================================================================
```

CircleAvatar absolute not null, why would this error happen? where is the problem and what should I do to fix it? I have tried get image outside the build method like this:

```
  NetworkImage getImage(){
    NetworkImage ni = NetworkImage(
      'https://source.unsplash.com/50x50/?portrait',
    );
    return ni;
  }
```

it seems not work. I tried to load image from local:

```
CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 20,
                    backgroundImage: AssetImage('lib/resouce/icon/ProcessedImages/Icon-App-83.5x83.5@3x.png'),
                  ),
```

also did not work, this is the assets config in `pubspec.yaml`:

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true
  assets:
    - lib/resouce/icon/ProcessedImages/Icon-App-83.5x83.5@3x.png
```

and this is the image path:

[image]

I found the image bundle is null:

[image]

and have no clue to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetworkImage('https://source.unsplash.com/50x50/?portrait') is likely what's null. When flutter calls the build method it expects the build method to instantly return a result so that it can render 120 frames per second. That means it won't wait for any webrequest to happen.

You have to load your image from the internet outside of the build method.

Comment: how to know the NetworkImage load complete? I have move the NetworkImage outside the build methond. Seems not fix this problem.@Christian

Comment: I looked more into the documentation and it seems CircleAvatar is supposed to show a background before the image is loaded so what I thought isn't the actual issue. I copied your code into an example and it works without throwing errors. If I would be you I would use the debugger and see where exactly the null error gets thrown and what's null.

Comment: for a long time and I read the source code silient, I finally found out it must set the backgroundColor. but the demo from internet no one mention about this@Christian

Comment: @Dolphin : While it makes a lot of sense to set backgroundColor, it seems to default to blue on my device, when I copypasted your code.

Answer (score 0):

upon further investigation, the null check error can be avoided if you use a late identifier on a variable. move the image url into said variable and then use it in the NetworkImage(url). i.e: late var url; then in the build method using the CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: NetworkImage(url),)   This will avoid the null check error, however the image will still take it's time to load on to the circle avatar widget. Atleast you avoid red error screen.